# Stop reading input when a key is pressed

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I'm new to programming and have started learning with Python. One of the problems in my workbook asks me to keep accepting input until a key is pressed. I came up with two solutions and am wondering if one is preferred over the other. Someone told me I should avoid conditions that create infinite loops, so I'm wondering about Solution 1. Here they are:

**Solution 1**

```
while True:
integer = int(input("Please enter an integer (0 exits): "))
if integer != 0:
    list.append(integer)
else:
    break
```

**Solution 2**

```
integer = int(input(“Enter an integer (0 exits): “))
while integer != 0:
    list.append(integer)
    integer = int(input(“Enter an integer (0 exits): “))
```

Comment: Are you asking which one is better?

Comment: The second example is more readable and has less code.

Comment: Personal preference (or following the style manual for somewhere you work).  I prefer the first (and obviously cdonts prefers the second).  My rationale is I prefer not to repeat any line of code, and the while true seems more readable to me.  Personal preference.

Comment: The last line of code is not required in the second solution.

Comment: Neither is pythonic as you should be using a try/except, your code will error for a multitude of inputs

Comment: Thanks everyone. From the responses, I gathered that it's a matter of personal opinion between the two solutions I posted. And it sounds like there will be even a more appropriate way to solve this problem once I get to exception handling chapter in my book. Thanks again for the informative responses.

Comment: @Katpoes Yes it is ;P If it weren't there it would just create an infinite loop of adding an integer to the list.

Comment: @Iplodman you are right, that code however wasn't formatted correctly. You have to remove the first integer input and swap the 3rd and 4th line.

Comment: Well, it was formatted correctly, it just wasn't optimal :p

Answer (score 1):

More pythonic way:

```
sentinel = 0
[int(n) for n in iter(input,sentinel)]

Input:
1
2
4
0
Result:
[1,2,4]
```

You need to be careful with string input like chars or special chars. You need to add some try/catch code to handle those cases.

Comment: enter `""` and see what happens  when casting to int

Comment: @PadraicCunningham im not casting to int.

Comment: @levi OP is casting to int.

Comment: @Katpoes  But if you add a cast, is the same as OP did. It would fail. He should handle that case, is up to him how he want to  catch the error.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you can use a for loop then.

Comment: @joelgoldstick ok but downvote for that ? I mean, is not bad learn or try to learn some "advance" stuff.

Comment: I like @Katpoes solution because it uses basic language constructs, and introduces try/except which the OP hasn't gotten to yet.  list comprehensions and intertools are pretty cool, but if you are just starting to program, they aren't concepts readily understood.

Comment: @joelgoldstick yes u right, I got it, but upvote his answer, not downvote mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
final = []
while True:
    try:
        integer = int(input("Enter an integer (0 exits): "))
        if integer == 0: break
        final.append(integer)
    except:
        print ("Input wasn't a int.")
```

Tried keeping it as close to your existing solutions and as readable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a `lambda`  with  `iter`  to allow you to add a string to your input to give the user message and a `try/except` to catch any values entered that cannot be cast to an int outputting an appropriate message to the user, the second arg to iter is a sentinel value which will break the loop once entered. It must be a string as we are not casting until we get to the try/except:

```
res = []
for val in iter(lambda: input("Please enter an integer (0 exits): "), "0"):
    try:
        res.append(int(val))
    except ValueError:
        print("Integers only")
print(res)
```

We need the lambda as the first arg to iter must be callable so because we have added the user output message we will have already called the function.